# Prestashop Slider

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How to setup a slider at the bottom-right corner in Prestashop like the picture? This slider consists of different picture. When I click an image, relative information will be shown on the right corner.

Comment: Image 1: http://i68.tinypic.com/33djmn5.png
Image 2: http://i67.tinypic.com/33bz4o4.png

Answer (score 0):

Simple you need to build a custom module. Please ref to prestashop.com document how you build custom module.

On that module hook the theme file yourmodulefile.tpl at FOOTER

Then make a wrap Div, set a class "footer_slide_wrap"

On your module CSS mark that class as bellow

```
.footer_slide_wrap{
display :fixed;
bottom : 0;
right :0;
width : 30px;
height:auto;
}
```

Now your DIV with class footer_slide_wrap will be place on that place. 
now insert an UL and put your all button under li in this UL.

You can make the div .footer_slide_wrap mouse over slidable. For that you need to make a default div with class .opener and make the wrap hide.

need to create a javascript function to hide / show the DIV on mouse over.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register a custom hook inside your slider module's php file, eg: "footerslider" then add the hook to your fooeter.tpl file which is located at "themes/yourthemes/footer.tpl" by placing this code {hook h="fooerslider"}

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, you should create small module that have hook.
>   Prestashop has many hooks related with your layout but if they are not suitable for you, you can create your own hook.

If you want to call your custom hook, simply put this code where you want to show.

```
 {hook h="displayYourHookName"}
```

> You need to install your custom hook in your install() function of your custom module.

```
// use this code in your install() function   
$this->registerHook('displayYourHookName');

// your custom hook
public function hookDisplayYourHookName()
{
    // code ...
    // your html template that you want to show
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'yourTemplate.tpl');
}
```

if you are using default hook, prestashop will call automatically.

I hope this will help, cheers :)